# How do you establish the parent of an object as an object in page object?

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

In a page object file:

```
class ThisPage
  include PageObject
```

I can establish an object like this:

```
div(:user_dialog, :class => 'ud_dialog')
```

However, in the domain of the website, there are many windows with `:class => 'ud_dialog'` that popup in various workflows.

I can get to the object in **binding.pry** like this:

```
on(ThisPage).div_elements(:text => 'Are you sure you want to do this action?').first.parent.html
```

How can I establish the window like this in the page file?

i.e. is there some syntax like this:

```
div(:user_dialog, parent(:text => 'Are you sure you want to do this action?'))
```

Comment: What language and/or platform is this? Ruby?

Comment: It's good to add the language name tag, so other users of the language are more likely to see the question. I've added it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complex locators, such as locating the parent element, you can use a block to get the element.

If you define the div in your page object as:

```
div(:user_dialog){
  div_elements(:text => 'Are you sure you want to do this action?').first.parent
}
```

Then your page can do:

```
on(ThisPage).user_dialog_element.html
```

Note that since you want the first matching div, you could simplify it to:

```
div(:user_dialog){
  div_element(:text => 'Are you sure you want to do this action?').parent
}
```

It might also be possible to be more direct by using multiple locators (depending on what your html is). You could locate the div that has the ud_dialog class and contains the specified text (a partial match since there is likely other text):

```
div(:user_dialog, :class => 'ud_dialog', 
  :text => /Are you sure you want to do this action?/)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. Where does one go to find this information (and more like it)?

Comment: The documentation and experience are the only ideas I have. Reading Cheezy's (he is the creator of the gem) blog and book might also help.